# How can I subscript and superscript my labels? I can't seem to get it working for ggdensity plots

Tags: r, plot, subscript, superscript

I want to subscript the '2' in 'NO2' in the main heading and the xlabel, and I want to add '(µg/m3)' (with a superscript '3') in the xlabel, but the way I did it before for histograms doesn't work. Any help would be gratefully received!
This is what I have so far:

```
library(ggpubr)

ggdensity(bgbind$no2,
main = "Density plot of background NO2 concentrations",
xlab = "NO2")
```

Comment: You can copy and paste this superscript 3 `³` and this subscript 2 `₂` straight from this comment into your label text. That should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the symbols directly:

```r
ggdensity(bgbind$no2, 
          main = "Density plot of background NO₂ concentrations", 
          xlab = "NO₂ (µg/m³)")
```

A somewhat more portable way of doing this is using unicode escape sequences. I tend to do this by looking up, say, "unicode subscript 2" in a web search engine. This will usually give you the result in the format "U+AAAA" where "AAAA" is a four digit hexadecimal number. If you do `"\uAAAA"` as a string in R, this will be converted to the appropriate unicode symbol. So, for example, look at what prints in the console here:

```r
"NO\u2082 (\u03BCg/m\u00bB)"
#> [1] "NO₂ (μg/m»)"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried these suggestions in various combinations but  unfortunately they didn't seem to work for me. For example, the following code produces a plot with a superscript 3 (which was cut and paste) but the cut and paste 2 was normal and the unicode produces a square:

...
Iggdensity(bgbind$no2, 
main = "Density plot of background NO₂ concentrations", 
xlab = "NO\u2082 (µg/m³)")
...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bquote()`.

Here is an example with ggplot2:

```r
library(ggplot2)

bgbind <- data.frame(
  no2 = 1:10,
  y = 1:10
)

ggplot(bgbind, aes(no2, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = bquote("Density plot of background NO"[2] ~ "concentrations"),
       x = bquote(NO[2] ~ (mu*g/m^3)))
```

Assuming that, by `main`, you meant the title of the plot.

[image]

I cannot test it as I don't have your dataset and I am unable to install the package ggpubr for some reason, but in your situation, this should work:

```r
library(ggpubr)

ggdensity(bgbind$no2,
          main = bquote("Density plot of background NO"[2] ~ "concentrations"),
          xlab = bquote(NO[2] ~ (mu*g/m^3)))
```

Inside `bquote()`, `[]` subscripts what is inside, `^` superscripts what follows, `~` adds a space, `mu` is turned into the symbol micro, `*` juxtaposes 2 elements.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Unfortunately, when using that code I am presented with the error message:

Error: Element 4 of `.l` must be a vector, not a `formula` object


It is so bizarre as none of the standard methods seem to work with this for some reason. Perhaps should I be using another package than ggdensity to make these plots?

Comment: You should share a minimum reproducible example so that people can see what you are doing. We don't have enough info to help you further.

Comment: Here is your solution: https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/annotate_figure.html. You have to pass the expression into `text_grob()`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpubr/versions/0.4.0/topics/text_grob

Comment: Actually, that was for an arranged figure, which may not be your case. We really need more info about your code. What is for sure however, is that they are using `bquote()` in that example. So `bquote()` works. You need to figure out why it doesn't work as is.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help. I followed the link and did some cutting and pasting and it seems to work now. I have no idea what I was doing wrong but I basically ended up cutting and pasting the example provided and changing the characters within, which worked for me. Thanks again to you all!